# codeigniter htaccess php instructions not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

In my php.ini I have disabled file upload globally:

```
file_uploads = Off
```

And i tried to enable file upload for my codeigniter site only. So i added to the .htaccess file the following:

```
php_flag file_uploads 1
```

And I made sure that `AllowOverride` is setup as follow in the `apache config file`:

```
<Directory /var/www/my_codeigniter_app/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

However file upload is not working. It only works, when I enable file upload globally.

Comment: where are you writing to? any apache error logs to see?

Comment: You need to add `php.ini` on you root folder of your project. And you need to enable file upload through root `php.ini`.

Comment: You can only change PHP settings from within .htaccess, if PHP is running as an Apache module.

Comment: @Stuart apache error log file is empty as there is no error. The problem is that file_uploads setting is ignored.

Comment: @hardiksolanki i added the php.ini at the root folder of my project then added the `file_uploads on` but still no luck

Comment: @misorude of course i did. Please read again my OP

Comment: @redochka Did you add like this `file_uploads = On`?

Comment: _“of course i did. Please read again my OP”_ - I did not even tell you to do anything, or ask you if you did - so what kind of response is “of course I did” then …?

Comment: @misorude you said: *You can only change PHP settings from within .htaccess* . If you read my OP, you wouldn't say this.

Comment: @hardiksolanki Yes i added: `file_uploads = On` in php.ini in the root folder of the application

Comment: _“If you read my OP, you wouldn't say this”_ - why wouldn’t I? Isn’t that exactly what you are having trouble with, changing settings from within .htaccess? That is only possible, if you have PHP running as an Apache module. What exactly in your posting would tell me that this was the case?

Comment: @misorude sorry, i see. i completely ignore the CGI mode. I am running PHP as an Apache module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the `file_uploads` directive via `.htaccess`.

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), `file_uploads` is a `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` type setting. That means you can only set it [via `php.ini` and `httpd.conf`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php).

To enable it only for your CodeIgniter site, you can set the directive in your VirtualHost configuration by using `php_admin_value` instead of `php_value`, since `php_value` [can only set](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) `PHP_INI_ALL` or `PHP_INI_PERDIR` level settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_codeigniter_app
    # [...] all your other settings

    php_admin_value file_uploads 1
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't have a VirtualHost config for your CodeIgniter site, you *might* be able to also set it in the `<Directory>` section of your Apache config (again, using `php_admin_value`), although I haven't tried that myself so I'm not 100% sure that'll work:

```
<Directory /var/www/my_codeigniter_app/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    php_admin_value file_uploads 1
</Directory>
```